# remote control for XBMC and transmission

Tags: networking, remote, kodi

I have raspberry pi 3 B and i have installed there XMBC (Kodi) and Transmission (torrent-client).
So i have a trouble here:

Few days ago i have changed my provider. Now i have a router, which translate wifi at 2.4GHz and 5GHz waves. I have two devices which i used to connect to Transmission and XBMC (remote, both) - phone and tablet. I'm used androind aplications on this devices for remote connection.
My phone not supporting wifi-standart 802.11ac (5GHz), but tablet support both waves. And now, only tablet manage to connect to Transmission and XBMC via wifi and only with 5GHz.
Why it works like this? Can i change something in routher/raspberry so it would be work at both wifi-waves?

Raspberry connected with home network via wire.
thx.

Comment: Please read: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: @MatsK, what have i read about?

Comment: Are you sure it's not the other way around? RPi only supports 2.4GHz, so it normally should end up in using the same SSID as other 2.4GHz-only devices.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, yes, i sure. But you've not understood - Rpi connected to router by wire. ~~~~~~~ Дмитрий, малина в роутере через кабель включена, я же говорю о том, что девайсы работающие по вайфаю, раздающемуся через этот роутер, могут подключиться только через сеть 5Ghz.

Comment: @Дмитрий Right, I overlooked the last sentence. Anyhow, I don't think you'll get a useful answer here: the core of the issue is the router configuration. Try asking this on superuser.com, and make sure to include your router's model in the question. It would also be helpful to know what IP addresses your devices get on 5GHz / 2.4GHz / cable connections. Are they all in the same subnet?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with this"question" and the OP did not seem to understand MatsK's pointer to the help pages (presumably provided as this is a poor match for Stack Exchange style questions) so the question may get edited or removed, but my response for part one asking about slow Transmission download speed is this:

It could quite easily occur that the download speed is less than your connection speed for a variety of reasons (most of which are unrelated to your Pi) I would guess that the most likely is the # seeders but suggest you try to rule out a network configuration problem, and confirm that your ISP is not traffic shaping. For a comprehensive list, see here on the Transmission github wiki page: https://github.com/transmission/transmission/wiki/Why-Are-My-Speeds-So-Slow%3F